# Jquery: pass attr, destroy attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I turn this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="Menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="Menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Into this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" catid="Menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" catid="Menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" catid="Menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

In Jquery using .attr

Thanks.

Comment: You already know you can use `attr()` to achieve this, so you solved half your problem. Did you try anything?

Comment: `catid` is not valid html.  Consider using `data-catid` instead.

Comment: @shanabus this one solves the trick. I need to store the category id from a link in wordpress. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('ul li a').each(function() {

  var self = $(this);
  self.attr('catid', self.attr('href'));
  self.attr('href', '#');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you:

```
$('a').attr('catid', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('href', '#');
    return href;
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbtJn/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li a").each(function(){
    $(this)
        .attr("catid", $(this).attr("href"))
        .attr("href", "#");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('catid',$(this).attr('href'));
    $(this).attr('href', '#');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("ul li a").each(function(){
    var catid = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('catid', catid);
    $(this).attr('href', '#');
});
```

Comment: Damn, I should read the question more carefully before posting. Deserved the downvotes for that. Anyway, I fixed my answer right away